# How to remove row from rows object, not from database?

Tags: python, web2py

I have a rows object and want to delete a row from it, similar to removing items from a list. Regular python method `rows.remove(row)` doesn't work and I don't want to use DAL's built in delete methods since they delete the whole record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`exclude`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#find--exclude--sort) method:

```
rows.exclude(lambda r: r.id == some_id)
```

Of course, you can filter by any condition you like.